# xmemcached set byte array

Tags: xmemcached

Im using xmemcached to write memcacheclient. Now I want to have a method like: set(key, byte[]) and get(key) return byte[] in memcache client. Anyone can suggest me something to do that in XMEMCACHED.
In my case, Im using protocol buffer to serial/deserial objects, then store them to Memcache.
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to get byte[] value with XMemcached I implemented my own transcoder:

```
public class ByteArrayTranscoder implements net.rubyeye.xmemcached.transcoders.Transcoder<byte[]>
{

    @Override
    public byte[] decode(CachedData d)
    {
        return d.getData();
    }
    @Override
    public CachedData encode(byte[] o)
    {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
    // UnsupportedOperationException for all other methods
}
```

Usage:

```
byte[] value = client.get(queueName, new ByteArrayTranscoder())
```

Probably, the same trick can be done for setting value, though I didn't tried it.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can set the byte array directly.

Comment: this does not provide an answer to the question. it's just a hint or rather a notion and should be posted as a comment under the question. even if it was... in majority of cases one short sentence is *not* helpful. even if you know the technology well, OP might not.